# httpclient.execute(httppost) issue with Android 4.0 and higher

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm writing an application for Android. The application connects to a server to retrieve comments.
The code of interest is:

```
BufferedReader input = null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.domain.com/personal_proj/directorydirectory/file.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.i("TEST","after httpclient.execute()");
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I tested this code in HTC Wildfire, HTC Desire Z and it works. If this code is executed in Android 4.0+, it never reach the line

```
Log.i("TEST","after httpclient.execute()");
```

, the server never gets the request and it never throw an exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Charlie Collins i have noticed that i have not handled well the exception. The exception that i captured it's android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. This means that i can't perform a networking operation on the main thread (this is thrown for applications targeting 3.0+). Using AsyncTask worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the default connection and socket timeout parameters are for the no arg constructed DefaultHttpClient, but I'd check that, or set the params:

`HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 20000);`

Then construct your HttpClient with the params:

`new DefaultHttpClient(params)`

At that point you should at least get the timeout, if no other response.

Also look at [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) (it sets up reasonable timeouts, among other things like gzip support), and consider the advice to [prefer HttpUrlConnection](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) (though there are caveats with that).

Comment: It 's weird to explain, but with your help I have noticed that I have not handled well the exception. See my answer.

Comment: Glad you got it, but yeah, you should never do a network op or any other long running background stuff on the main thread.